# Flutter : WebViewWidget in flutter refreshes continue when a count down function was called onPageFinnished

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using `WebViewWidget` to display a webview in my app, I called a method with count down `onPageFinished` but am facing an issue with the webview refreshing every second of the countdown and eventually crashing the app. I am not sure what am doing wrong but below is my code.

My WebView is as below:

```
                         Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                      child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color:
                                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                            borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(0),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                              'Time Remaining: ${getFormattedTime()}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.justify))),
                                  
                                  WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
```

Below is the countdown method implemented:

```
  int _secondsRemaining = 300; // 5 minutes (300 seconds)
  late Timer _timer;

  void startCountdownTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_secondsRemaining > 0) {
          _secondsRemaining--;
        } else {
          _timer.cancel(); // Cancel the timer when countdown is complete
        }
      });
    });
  }

  String getFormattedTime() {
    final minutes = (_secondsRemaining / 60).floor();
    final seconds = _secondsRemaining % 60;
    return '$minutes:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
```

Below is my webview controller :

```
final WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');

             setState(() {
                startCountdownTimer();
            });
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('myurl')) {
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
            debugPrint('url change to ${change.url}');
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          debugPrint("message:$message");
          print(message.message);
          var res = json.decode(message.message);
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(
          "Myurl"));
```

Comment: So what is the solution? Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Sorry I think the `setState` on `startCountdownTimer` will rebuild `WebViewWidget` every second.

Comment: I suggest to create `TimeRemainingWidget` class and refresh time remaining by calling `setState` inside.